# Python 2, Python 3 and Anaconda on Windows 10. Now attempting to get Tensorflow to run

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tensorflow, anaconda

I have Windows 10 (64-bit computer) with Python 2. Here is the output on the `cmd >`:

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) 
[MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

which is visible in `C:\Python27`.

In the same folder there is Python 3: `C:\Python36-32`.

In my path I have `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts` which seems to default to `Project Interpreter: 2.7.13 (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python.exe)`.

So after much hair pulling and retrofitting code in Python 3 (you can check my previous posts to get an idea), I get Python 2 up and running.

Only that what I am most interested in is Google's choice of Python for ML - in particular Tensorflow. And, alas, Tensorflow runs on Python 3!

No problem, right? After all I had downloaded and installed it in `C:\`... Wrong!

If I go to PyCharms and try installing Tensorflow after selecting Python3, this is what I get:

[image]

OK... So I go to the terminal prompt, and try there:

```
C:\Users\Toni>pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

But this may be because I have Python2?

So I go to Google, and find this [promising post](http://chris35wills.github.io/conda_python_version/), which makes me think that going to `cmd >` and entering `conda install python=3.5.0` will do the trick.

The problem is that if I run this, I am asked to un-install a bunch of stuff that I have painfully gotten to work, for example the `autograd` package...

Can I get some help as to how to get to run Tensorflow from this point in Dante's np.inferno?

Comment: You can try to follow this steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322964/permission-denied-when-installing-tensorflow/44442734#44442734 and use Spyder or Jupyter

Answer (score 1):

That is precisely to avoid those conflicts that conda has environments, in which you can install a fresh and separate conda distribution.

In your case, you could start creating an environment (named `tensorflow` here, could be anything else) specifically for tensorflow by calling

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

then put yourself in the environment with

```
activate tensorflow
```

and from there install tensorflow as you mentionned.

I must say that all of this is actually pretty well explained in [tensorflow's installation tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).