# Conda closes automatically after installing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I tried to install tensorflow with following steps:

1. conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
2. activate tensorflow
3. conda install jupyter
4. conda install scipy
5. pip install tensorflow-gpu

As soon as I installed, conda shuts down immediately. I am using 64 bit windows and Anaconda 3.5. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should use conda to install tensorflow. Pip often causes problems.

```
    conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Have a look to these steps to install first CPU version: [Permission denied when installing Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322964/permission-denied-when-installing-tensorflow/44442734#44442734)