# Error importing Tensorflow from Anaconda environment

Tags: linux, tensorflow, anaconda, keras

I am quite a newbie with Anaconda and Tensorflow.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 x64, I have installed Anaconda and works ok. After, I have installed Tensorflow following precise instructions from Tensorflow website:

```
$ conda create -n tensorflow
$ source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow)$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tfBinaryURL
```

And I has also installed ok. I have activated the new environment, launched Spyder and tested the tensorflow test installation program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

And I get the error importing Tensorflow:

```
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

Is there any environment variable to change? How can I solve this? I know it can ba a simple question, but I would appreciate a lot any advise for this...

PD: My intention is to later install Keras. Should it be as simple as activating the environment and install Keras using pip?

Comment: I suspect you just ran Python from command line? You need to run the specific python from the environment you created, because on Ubuntu Python is a variable that points to the default instance, which is not where your Tensorlfow is installed.

Comment: Did you test the program on Spyder? How did you launch Spyder? In order to use Spyder you have to install Spyder within the environment you created for TensorFlow and launch Spyder from this same prompt. Although these instructions are for Windows, they may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322964/permission-denied-when-installing-tensorflow/44442734#44442734

Comment: That was right in both cases, thank you both a lot... problem solved.