# Is it needed to install Cuda Toolkit from NVIDIA in Win10 to use Cuda when you already have cudatoolkit package in your Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, nvidia

I have cudatoolkit and cudnn packages installed in my anaconda environment but tensorflow does not recognize my GPU device. In some web sources I have seen that you can use Cuda by only installing necessary anaconda packages. So, what I would like to know is that do I have to install NVIDIA Cuda from its website to be able to use it or would it lead to conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something wrong with your environment variables. I can recommend these steps:

- Create a new environment
- Install required packages:
  `conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0 python3 -m pip install tensorflow`
- Verify the installation, first import tensorflow
  `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf;`
- Then check the GPU
  `print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"`

This should be work
`

Comment: Does it work without installing anything from NVIDIA? Only these steps are sufficient?

Comment: Yeah, to work with Deeplabcut I have followed these steps and it worked. If it doesn't in your situation, you can write the problem here.

Comment: Installing tensorflow using pip ended up with a permission error as before. Is using pip required?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322964/permission-denied-when-installing-tensorflow check out this post

Comment: I solved tensorflow install problem. You just cannot install it into new environment because when you activate it somehow some files are blocked then permission error occurs. So, I have installed it to my base environment. Now I will reinstall cudnn following the rest of the steps.